# R: join 2 files automatically by import and name string

Tags: r, join

I am trying to import several files from 2 different directories, each containing ~ 40 txt.files. While importing I want to merge 1 file from each directory by a common name pattern. To be more specific, I want to use a loop - or any other way - that the name matching is done automatically. Finally, I´d like to write the joined files into a .txt.
Is there any way?

What I got so far (mainly by pasting different things together):

```
ls<-list.files("C:/directory1....", pattern=".txt")
ls1<-list.files("C:/directory2....", pattern=".txt")

get<-list()

for(i in 1:length(ls)){
  import<-read.table(file=paste("C:/directory1...), ls[i], sep="")
  get[[gsub(".txt","",ls[i)]]<-import
} 

get2<-list()

for(i in 1:length(ls1)){
  import<-read.table(file=paste("C:/directory2...), ls[i], sep="")
  get2[[gsub(".txt","",ls[i)]]<-import
}
```

...this is basically it, that I don´t know how to proceed. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: The files are all tabular data of the same dimension with the same headings?

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "I want to merge 1 file from each directory by a common name pattern" with an example?

Comment: Also, you've got some syntax errors in your code - some missing quotes at the least.

Comment: It would be good to see a sample of data from each file that needs to be matched, what the output you expect and also some sample patterns of the file names in each directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might work for you. Since there wasn't any data in the question, I've demonstrated how it would work with some local files that I have:

```
path1 <- "./Bolt Exercise/"
path2 <- "./gmad/R/"

all_files <- c(paste(path1, dir(path1, "*.xlsx"), sep = ""),
              paste(path2, dir(path2, "*.R"), sep = ""))

common_pattern <- "SLDASM"

read_func <- function(z){
  cols <- c("item","qty","per_unit","description","dwg_no","drw","dimension",
            "length","material","weight","surface","revision")
  return(readxl::read_xlsx(z, skip = 10, col_names = cols))
}

lapply(grep(common_pattern, all_files, val = T),read_func)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> all_files
 [1] "./Bolt Exercise/001600211.SLDASM.F Grupo done.xlsx"  
 [2] "./Bolt Exercise/001600234.SLDASM.F fadhili done.xlsx"
 [3] "./Bolt Exercise/001600240.SLDASM.D Gulf done.xlsx"   
 [4] "./gmad/R/calcCorrProperties.R"                       
 [5] "./gmad/R/getWeatherData.R"                           
 [6] "./gmad/R/getWeatherForecast.R"                       
 [7] "./gmad/R/gmadPlot.R"                                 
 [8] "./gmad/R/listMerge.R"                                
 [9] "./gmad/R/listTimeSegments.R"                         


> grep(common_pattern, all_files, val = T)
[1] "./Bolt Exercise/001600211.SLDASM.F Grupo done.xlsx"   "./Bolt Exercise/001600234.SLDASM.F fadhili done.xlsx"
[3] "./Bolt Exercise/001600240.SLDASM.D Gulf done.xlsx" 

> lapply(grep(common_pattern, all_files, val = T),read_func)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 6,157 x 12
          item   qty per_unit                        description       dwg_no   drw
         <chr> <chr>    <chr>                              <chr>        <chr> <chr>
 1        Item   Qty per unit                        Description Art./Dwg.No.   Drw
 2         001     1        1 Pulse Air Intake System SGT6-8000H    100600415     X
 3     001.001     8        8                 Weather hood upper    121000398     X
 4 001.001.001     1        8                         Bent plate    950067012     X
 5 001.001.002     1        8                         Bent plate    950067015     X
 6 001.001.003     1        8                         Bent plate    950067016     X
 7 001.001.100     8       64                               Bolt   1701339-04  <NA>
 8 001.001.101     8       64                                Nut      1701340  <NA>
 9 001.001.102    16      128                             Washer      1700581  <NA>
10 001.001.103     1        8                   Sealing Compound      1001531  <NA>
# ... with 6,147 more rows, and 6 more variables: dimension <chr>, length <chr>, material <chr>, weight <chr>,
#   surface <chr>, revision <chr>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5,100 x 12
                      item   qty per_unit                  description       dwg_no   drw  dimension length
                     <chr> <chr>    <chr>                        <chr>        <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>
 1                    Item   Qty per unit                  Description Art./Dwg.No.   Drw  Dimension Length
 2                     001     1        1 Air Intake System SGT6-5000F    100600470     X       <NA>   <NA>
 3                 001.001     1        1            Support structure    134600414     X       <NA>   <NA>
 4             001.001.001     1        1        Support structure Top    930603648     X       <NA>   <NA>
 5         001.001.001.001     1        1                         Beam    930603660     X       <NA>   <NA>
 6     001.001.001.001.001     1        1                         Beam    930603831     X       <NA>   <NA>
 7 001.001.001.001.001.001     1        1                         Beam    970023245  <NA> HM500x300A  10304
 8 001.001.001.001.001.002     5        5                        Plate    970023246     X         16   <NA>
 9 001.001.001.001.001.003     1        1                        Plate    970023437     X         16   <NA>
10 001.001.001.001.001.004     1        1                        Plate    970023286     X         16   <NA>
# ... with 5,090 more rows, and 4 more variables: material <chr>, weight <chr>, surface <chr>, revision <chr>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2,357 x 12
          item   qty per_unit       description       dwg_no   drw       dimension length        material
         <chr> <chr>    <chr>             <chr>        <chr> <chr>           <chr>  <chr>           <chr>
 1        Item   Qty per unit       Description Art./Dwg.No.   Drw       Dimension Length        Material
 2         001     1        1 Air Intake System    100600492     X            <NA>   <NA>            <NA>
 3     001.001     2        2      Weather hood    121600341     X            <NA>   <NA>            <NA>
 4 001.001.001     3        6        Bent plate    970025024     X               3   <NA> ASTM A572 Gr 50
 5 001.001.002     3        6        Bent plate    970025025     X               3   <NA> ASTM A572 Gr 50
 6 001.001.003     1        2        Bent plate    970025022     X               3   <NA> ASTM A572 Gr 50
 7 001.001.004     3        6        Bent plate    970025023     X               3   <NA> ASTM A572 Gr 50
 8 001.001.005     1        2        Bent plate    970025028     X               3   <NA> ASTM A572 Gr 50
 9 001.001.006     1        2        Bent plate    970025029     X               3   <NA> ASTM A572 Gr 50
10 001.001.100    24       48              Bolt      1001477  <NA> M10x20, ISO4017      0        8.8, HDG
# ... with 2,347 more rows, and 3 more variables: weight <chr>, surface <chr>, revision <chr>
```

If you want to combine the output for a given `common_pattern` into a single `data.table`, you can enclose the `lapply` call in `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(.....), use.names = T, fill = T)` - assuming you have the same structure for all files as in the above example:

```
> head(data.table::rbindlist(lapply(grep(common_pattern, all_files, value = T), read_func), use.names = T, fill = T))
          item qty per_unit                        description       dwg_no drw dimension length       material
1:        Item Qty per unit                        Description Art./Dwg.No. Drw Dimension Length       Material
2:         001   1        1 Pulse Air Intake System SGT6-8000H    100600415   X        NA     NA             NA
3:     001.001   8        8                 Weather hood upper    121000398   X        NA     NA Galvanized G90
4: 001.001.001   1        8                         Bent plate    950067012   X        NA     NA Galvanized G90
5: 001.001.002   1        8                         Bent plate    950067015   X        NA     NA Galvanized G90
6: 001.001.003   1        8                         Bent plate    950067016   X        NA     NA Galvanized G90
     weight             surface revision
1:   Weight             Surface Revision
2: 244436.3             14125.6        C
3:       51                 4.8        A
4:       41  3.8879999999999999        A
5:      4.7 0.45200000000000001        B
6:      4.7 0.45200000000000001        A
```

for multiple `common_patterns`, you can use a nested `lapply/sapply` statement.